# JQuery UI Tabs width JSON Response

Tags: json, jquery-ui, tabs

I have some tabs with jquery ui. Each link should receive a json response, but I am unable to make it work.
This is the active one:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ui-tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
            <a href="/comments.json" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">comments</a>
          </li>
```

response is:

```
[{"created_at":"2013-07-12T22:51:46Z","id":8,"programa_id":88,"sent_at":"2013-07-12T22:51:46Z","texto":"testing","updated_at":"2013-07-12T22:51:46Z","user_id":null}]
```

I tried several things, but best approach is:

```
  $( "#tab_messages" ).tabs({
    heightStyle: "fill",
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.ajaxSettings.dataType = "json";
      ui.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(data) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(jsonData[0].texto);
        return  jsonData[1].texto;
      };

       ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
        ui.panel.html(
          "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
          "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
    }});
  });
```

Panel don't load (jqXHR.error appears), but **if I return jsonData[1].texto, it works**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but if I delete ui.jqXHR.error function and set panel's html from dataFilter, it seems to work:

```
      ui.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(data) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        var htmlpanel = "";
        $.each(jsonData, function(index, value){
          htmlpanel += "<li>" + value.texto + "</li>";
        });
        ui.panel.html(htmlpanel);
      };
```